# How to add another text box in reference to the 1st text box's input in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How do i repeat a text box after i opt for option "next" in mvc 3 and then add all the integer values entered into those text boxes.

suppose i entered 5 in one text box and then how to automatically open another text box asking for next input and so on...

Comment: I think javascript is the way

Comment: If you'd like to use JavaScript, please post the relevant html (html that your browser sees, *not* the server-side script that generates it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the textboxes in the code then hide exept on

on `lostfocus` event of first text box activate the 2nd one and so on

use java script in it (for best results)

see [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/)  it will help you